# www or http www for redirecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

This question may be asked many times but I couldn't able to get a clear answer, so please forgive me.

I've an ASP.NET MVC blog running successfully, recently I came to know that google see both the requests `http://www.myblog.com` and `http://myblog.com` as different.

So I thought of doing some redirect from one to other but not sure from which one to other I've to do the redirect. Means, I want to do the 301 redirect from `http://www` to `http://` or vice-versa.

Additionaly in the sitemap file I've specified the urls as `http://www.*` and in google web master tools the site is displayed as `http://www.myblog.com`.

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than redirect content you can specify [canonical references](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to instruct search engines which URL to index. Irrespective of which version of your URL google sees, it will see the content as the same and index your site under the `www.myblog.com` domain.

For example:

```
<head>
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.myblog.com" />
  ...
</head>
```

Comment: 301s should be used over canonical references where possible. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW5UL3lzBOA

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question: it doesn't matter which your preference is.

In response to Spolto's answer:

Canonical references are suggestions. Google has said they don't necessarily follow them as they are your preference. 301s, on the other hand, are authoritative.

Canonical is great for dynamic URLs or in e-commerce where products live in multiple places. Otherwise the preference should still be 301s and even setting the preference in GWT.

'Use 301s when you can' -- Matt Cutts
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW5UL3lzBOA

Answer (score 1):

For all my sites, I always elect to use the non-www authority (no subdomain) as my canonical URL, and I do 301 rewrites in .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydowmain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```